# msvcrt.kbhit() always returns false . Unable to detect Escape key

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10

I tried `if (msvcrt.getch() == chr(27).encode())`, it didn't work

The msrcvt.getch() in my program always prints to b'\xff' in the debug-print statement.

It simply didn't detects the ESC key I am pressing. How to make it work. Please provide any sample code for Python 3.8.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: if msvcrt.getch()==b'\x1b'

Ex:

```
import msvcrt
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        key_stroke = msvcrt.getch()
        if key_stroke==b'\x1b':
            print ("Esc key pressed")
        else:
            print (str(key_stroke).split("'")[1],"key pressed")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Homer. Actually, I have been using IDLE to run my Python script and it couldn't detect '**ESC**' . So that key was not detected through the IDLE Python console. In windows cmd prompt, it worked fine.
I came to know that I have to use `str(key_stroke)[2:3]` to detect the keys pressed correctly. For example: Pressing 'q' in keyboard. Please explain about it if possible.

Comment: @Homer Please check if you can find a solution for this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840829/detect-esc-keypress-while-expecting-input-in-python3-8-and-windows-10

Comment: key_stroke's object type is 'bytes', and output for key 'q' is: b'q'
type(key_stroke) = <class 'bytes'>

I converted it to a string type object, so it's easier to slice and get 'q' from b'q'.
str("b'q'")[2:3] = 'q'

But it won't work correctly for special keys like Enter, Backspace, etc, so I have modified my code to use str(key_stroke).split("'")[1] instead of str(key_stroke)[2:3].

It will work perfectly with all the keys. See code above.

Here, I am converting key_stroke to string type object and splitting it with ' as delimiter, and value of index 1 will be the key pressed

Comment: @Homer Great.Thank you so much for explaining.