# How to Detect 'ESC' keypress while expecting input() from user

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, msvcrt

I tried using

```
if msvcrt.kbhit():
  key_stroke = msvcrt.getch()

  if key_stroke==chr(27).encode(): #b'\x1b'
    print ("Esc key pressed")
    sys.exit()`
```

before and after the  `data=input('Enter a value:')` but the **Esc** key_stroke not getting detected

That is, while expecting an input from user with **input()** function, if the user press **Esc** key, I want to do `sys.exit()`

Comment: Haven't you asked that question already? [msvcrt.kbhit() always returns false . Unable to detect Escape key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63835241/msvcrt-kbhit-always-returns-false-unable-to-detect-escape-key)

Comment: Yes...But please make note of `input()` function. 

In previous question, it worked **without input()** function used. It's a test code that I learnt the basic use of msvcrt . 

with `input()` function used with msvcrt functions, it's not detecting any keys. Please Try this if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys
import msvcrt
def func():
    print ('Enter user input:')
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            key_stroke = msvcrt.getche()
            if key_stroke==chr(27).encode():
                print ("Esc key pressed")
                sys.exit()
            else:
                #print (str(key_stroke).split("'")[1],"key pressed")
                i=str(key_stroke).split("'")[1]+input()
                print ("User input:",i)
                            
func()
```

Note: I am using getche instead of getch, it is similar to getch but prints the key that is pressed.

Comment: Please provide your suggestion, msvcrt is good to use with windows OS. What library is the best to use under Linux OS that shall provide similar functions as above?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I think "getch" can be used.
https://pypi.org/project/getch/

Answer (score 0):

This worked,

```
import msvcrt

data=input('Enter a value : ')
if(data):
  print(data)
else:
  print('invalid value')
  key=msvcrt.getch()
  if(msvcrt.getch() == chr(27).encode()):
    print('Escape key pressed')
```

The main difference/relation between this and the said [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63835241/msvcrt-kbhit-always-returns-false-unable-to-detect-escape-key) question is that,

1. The `msvcrt.kbhit()` couldn't be used with **`input()`** function. because it always doesn't wait for the keyboard hit. So directly using the `msvcrt.getch()` works perfectly.
2. Both the code provided for the question is mainly based on msvcrt library and that library didn't work as expected in the Python IDLE console, but perfectly in the windows command prompt

Please correct me if I am wrong